# How to find all child elements inside a WebElement or List of WebElements in Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a `<section>` tag in which there is `<tfoot>` tags and many `<td>` tags.

I want to store the 1st & 4th td elements of a in a Map, but i get index out of bounds exception.

Now, how can we use FindElement or FindElement method on a WebElement itself. Does this  find all the child elements? Apologies as i have messed up all my code.

There are 14  tags on the page and i want to retrieve the text of td elements that  are inside tfoot tag from each and every section, Product name and price, then store it in a String, String Map. Also, there is lot of whitespace in td element values.

```
<div>
                <table class="right">
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr class="product">
                            <td>Product 1
                            </td>
                            <td class="rt">323.00</td>
                            <td class="rt">
                                6
                            </td>
                            <td class="rt">
                                6
                            </td>
                            <td class="rt">&nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
```

[image]
List sectionsList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("section"));

```
Iterator<WebElement> it = sectionsList.iterator();
while(it.hasnext())
{
System.out.println(itr.next().findElements(By.tagName("tfoot")).get(1).findElements(By.tagName("td")).get(0)
                    .getText());
```

Now, i want to store the td values in a Hashmap.

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();


for(int i=1; i<sections.size()+1; i++){ map1.put(sectionList.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("tfoot")).get(1).findElements(By.tagName("td")).get(0).getText() , sectionList.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("tfoot")).get(1).findElements(By.tagName("td")).get(3).getText()); }
```

Comment: Post your HTML Dom code reference

Comment: hi, done. thanks.

Comment: Please post it as code.

Comment: done. it would be helpful if you could review the  code.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=1; i<sections.size()+1; i++)
```

Why are you adding 1 to sections size, remove 1

```
for(int i=1; i<sections.size(); i++)
```

and also why starting from i=1 ? index starts from 0 to size-1 , so it should be i=0 ?